# How to insert DD/MM/YYYY into SQL Server DATE format?

Tags: sql-server, csv, date, insert, format

I'm trying to bulk insert a csv file and have columns which include dates that are in the DD/MM/YYYY format when the sql DATE format is YYYY-MM-DD and some are even D/M/YYYY as it isn't 01/01/2020 instead it is 1/1/2020 so I don't think I can slice the string.

[image: csv table]

```
BULK INSERT orders
    FROM 'C:\Orders.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\OrdersErrorRows.csv',
    TABLOCK
    );
```

Comment: How are you doing this bulk insert?

Comment: `set dateformat dmy` before you `BULK INSERT`

Comment: _sql DATE format is YYYY-MM-DD_ There is no such thing. Dates are stored as unreadable binary values. Formatting of dates for display purposes is a function of the tool you use to query the table. It would be FAR better to change the process that generates this information to a consistent and unambiguous format if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to date and specify the  format. Try the syntax referenced:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/